# Batch file renames files incorrectly

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using an executable file (called reduce.exe) to use two functions on PDB files and rename them once done, and am trying to do this to an entire file directory. I have a text file named pdblist.txt that sits right next to the batch file. My current file looks like this:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo off
for /F %%g in (pdblist.txt) do (
    set var=!%%g:~0,4!
    echo !var!
    set trim=!var!no_H.pdb
    echo !trim!
    set build=!var!h.pdb
    echo !build!
    reduce.exe -Trim %%g > !trim!
    reduce.exe -BUILD !trim! > !build!
)
```

However, when I run the batch file, it creates two files, called "~0,4h.pdb" and "~0,4no_H.pdb". I am supposed to end up with three files for each original file name, as in this example:

Original file name is 1csl.pdb, after the Trim function, it creates 1csl**_noH**.pdb, and after the BUILD function, it creates 1csl**h**.pdb

So, could you please explain why it is not creating two more files? Are the exclamation points in the wrong places on the set var line, or any other line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first set var to g, then truncate

```
for /F %%g in (pdblist.txt) do (
    set var=%%g
    set var2=!var:~0,4!
    set trim=!var2!no_H.pdb
    echo !trim!
    set build=!var2!h.pdb
    echo !build!
```

my pdblist.txt contains first_item, second_item (1 per line). output is:

```
first_item
firsno_H.pdb
firsh.pdb
second_item
secono_H.pdb
secoh.pdb
```